# Best practices for Azure Key Vault for multiple web services?

Tags: web-services, rest, security, azure, azure-keyvault

We have a project with multiple RESTful web services communicating with each other. So far, each web service has its own Azure Key Vault. They each have a powershell script that accesses information stored in the other web services' key vaults.

Is this the best practice, or should our project have one central key vault shared between the web services? If there isn't a clear answer, what might the decision be dependent on?

Answer (score 0):

I think this design is up to you and your needs. Personally I prefer a centralized location for all of my secrets, one source of truth, so one keyvault. This feels like a thoughtful design to me. Keyvaults are after all, designed to securely store secrets, so having multiples does not seem a design requirement.

However I will temper this with the fact that I have run into limitations where I have to create multiple keyvaults. Azure VM Scale Sets for example require that the keyvault be in the same region as the nodes of the scale set. No idea why, and seems unnecessary. For me this means the app I deploy in 8 regions must have their own keyvaults, duplicating the same keys in 8 places. Argh.